# configuration file editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ini, shell

Greetings,

Anybody uses Eclipse to edit configuration files like httpd.conf and the likes, or even shell scripts? Which editors are there for that?

Thanks.
Pedro.

Answer (score 5):

There's [shelled](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/), a shell editor plugin for Eclipse. Syntax highlighting is quite solid. It even provides mouse-hover docs for commands having a man page.

Answer (score 1):

there is a cool editor for http.conf called [ApacheConf](http://www.apache-gui.com/apacheconf/screenshots/index.html). Other than that I think Notepad++ does the trick but only for syntax highlight.

Comment: I use TextWrangler myself on the Mac. But I was trying to find something to use inside Eclipse, and not only httpd.conf, but configuration files in general and shell scripts in particular. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is great for this kind of tasks.

Comment: I was really trying to find an Eclipse editor for shell scripts in particular and configuration files in general. But thanks nevertheless.